# Python traversing two lists

Tags: python, list, traversal

I found this nice statement in a tutorial:

```
    for x,y in [(x,y) for x in listA for y in listB]:
```

Now, as for me, I understood, that that statment will traverse listA and listB and x is a value of list A and y is a value from listB. But in this example the two lists had the same length. Will this statement also give me all pairs, if one list is longer than the other, or do I have to use a different statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dude, this is so easy to answer by just typing something into python.  if you're trying to learn python you really need to use it.  i'm not criticising you for asking a question, just saying that you should use python interactively (at the prompt, not writing programs) - it's a useful skill and you will save yourself a lot of time with quick experiments.

Comment: I find little that is "nice" in this syntactic horror. As you just found out from @phihags answer: you failed to understand what this line stands for. Just because something compiles doesn't make it proper coding - this is not easily readable and thus goes against one of the main principals of python.

Comment: I have not completely been sure, so I thought, better ask than be sorry :-D

Comment: @andrew cooke - typing the question looks like it took about 3 times as long as it would have taken to type the sample code into the Python prompt in the first place. Why are people so afraid of trying these statements first?

Comment: it's ok to ask!  :o)   i just thought that maybe you didn't know that you could use python interactively, or didn't know how useful it was....

Comment: @andrew I always forget, that I am able to use it interactively :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code computes the cartesian product ([`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)), not [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) as you suggested.

For example, if the inputs are `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5]`, the result is:

```
(1,4)
(1,5)
(2,4)
(2,5)
(3,4)
(3,5)
```

For comparison, the result of `zip([1,2,3], [4,5])` is:

```
(1,4)
(2,5)
```

As you can see, zip (or [itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)) discards the additional items in the longer argument.

Its variant [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) replaces these missing elements with an arbitrary value. For example, `iterttools.izip_longest([1,2,3], [4,5], 99)` returns:

```
(1,4)
(2,5)
(3,99)
```

Comment: OP might nevertheless be looking for: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest

Comment: so there will be really all possible pairs, even, when one list has more elements than the other list EDIT: ah, now I saw the example. thanks

Comment: @markus: Well, if you get all combinations, then the lengths don't matter.

Comment: @Felix Kling was already editing to include that. Included ;)

Comment: *"zip(..) does indeed require both inputs to be of the same length.*" -> That's not true, it will discard elements from the longer lists.

Comment: @Felix Kling Oops. Better now?

Answer (score 6):

The example will produce all combinations of all the items in `listA` and `listB`.  Think of it as writing

```
for x in listA:
    for y in listB:
        …
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to add an answer for Traversing two list same at time.

```
alist = [1,2,3,4,5]
blist = [6,7,8,9,0]

for a,b in zip(alist,blist):
    print a,"+",b,'=',a+b
```

it will give output like

```
1 + 6 = 7
2 + 7 = 9
3 + 8 = 11
4 + 9 = 13
5 + 0 = 5
```